# How to generate 64 bit apk in android studio

Tags: android

How to make 64 bit APK file? How to ensure it's 64-bit apk.

I have used below code in my `build.gradle` file.

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit